# Rolling custom control buttons

Tags: mediaelement, mediaelement.js

do you have a reference or tutorial on customizing skins graphics/css for mejs?

here's what i've hacked on:

i copied the `mejs-ted` block in the `mejs-skins.css` file and renamed its elements to `mejs-custom`. i created a new PNG file similar to the existing `control-ted.png` and noted the coordinates of each control.  with those coordinates i changed the x/y offsets in mejs-custom (i could really use help with that, too).

but now how to activate this skin? and can you confirm the technique above is correct procedure to create skins?

http://mediaelementjs.com source has switchable skins, but the switching mechanism is pretty well obfuscated in the code, and the `mediaelementplayer-skins.html` file is missing from the `demos` section of the mu distribution.

Comment: i thought changeSkin() was the key... am i applying it incorrectly?

success: function (mediaElement, domObject) { 
 mediaElement.changeSkin('mejs-custom');
 mediaElement.play();
},

Comment: instead of switching skins as described above, i hacked on the `.mejs-controls` items in the default `mediaelementplayer.css`.  by changing the height/width of `.mejs-controls .mejs-button button`, and modifying the `background-position:` of various elements, you can come up with a fairly rudimentary approximation of a custom skin.

Comment: what a monsterous mess this has become.  i have to conclude that mediaelement.js is not for enthusiastic amateurs like myself and leave it to hardcore geeks for whom it was clearly intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your player then use the `changeSkin()` method to add the class of your skin to the container div, which is reflected in your skin css file

```
 var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player-ID');


   player.changeSkin('skin-container-class');
```

Then you can style all the elements.

```
.skin-container-class .mejs-controls {
/*stylez*/
}
```