# How to create a skin for mediaelement.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mediaelement.js

I used jPlayer before and the html markup of the player is in the page source directly, I'm trying mediaelement.js now, and I coded my audio player (html/css) but I don't know how to use it the right way with mediaelement.js.

so mediaelement.js adds the html markup to all the audio and video tags:

```
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer(); // using the jQuery version
```

so the only way to get the player's markup is to inspect the element with chrome developer tools and copy it.

but is this the right way to make a skin for mediaelement ? I think there must be a better way that I'm not aware of.

I searched but couldn't find any guides for this, I found this here on stackoverflow:

[Rolling custom control buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059843/rolling-custom-control-buttons/8357389#8357389)

And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually using inspect the element with chrome developer tools is the easy way to give style. At worst you can override it.

On the other hand I have to suggest you use mode:shim for browser supports

```
    $('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
    mode:'shim',
    startVolume: 0.8,
    loop: false,
    features: ['playpause','duration','volume'],
    success: function(player, node) {
    //success codes here
    }
});
```

Comment: well I think this is the best way to do it.